# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down while launching Chrome WebDrivers in Parallel

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Facing Connection pool shut down issue while launching multiple chrome drivers using testng - parallel execution.

Dependency used : webdrivermanager version: 1.6.2

Any solutions plz?

Comment: can you paste your code what you have done and also the logs for error you are getting?

Comment: `[2017-07-24 14:46:24:982] [TestNG-test=Smoke Test-2] WARN BrowserManager - [1/3] Exception reading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ to seek [chromedriver]: java.lang.IllegalStateException Connection pool shut down
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
 at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
 at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:189)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:257)
 `

Comment: Can someone help me in finding a solution for this.

Comment: please add the critical part of code you are using.

Comment: it seems that you are closing the connection pool and then try to use it again. maybe one thread is closing the pool and another wants to reuse it?